# "The value of a parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length"

Tags: apex, visualforce, managed-package, button

I'm getting this error when trying to override standard button of a custom object that is part of a managed package: "The value of a parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length." Specifically, the standard button is being overridden by a visualforce page.  Oddly, I do not encounter the error in our sandbox, but I do in production.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What's the managed package?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. Please [edit] your post to include more detail such if the Visualforce page is part of the package or a custom-built page, if the installed package is the same version in sandbox and prod, etc.

Comment: @AdrianLarson The managed package is ServiceMax.  It's built on Salesforce Platform.

Comment: @DavidCheng - The Visualforce page is a custom-built page, and yes I believe the installed package is the same version in prod and sandbox.

Comment: Please post your override details - URL you are creating.  Also, do you get the error when trying to save the override, or when using the override?

Comment: What happens if you spin up a new sandbox and try to set the override in the new sandbox?

Comment: I think this is due to the package license expiring.  We are looking to have it extended.  Thanks everyone for your input!